# Is there anyway to check whether relay has injected graphql server or not?

Tags: react-native, graphql, relay

Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
      new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer(`${GRAPHQL_SERVER}/graphql`)
    );

So How can I know graphql server has successfully injected this remote graphql server or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is a network layer implementation set via `Relay.Store._storeData._networkLayer._implementation`. If this is defined, your network layer has been injected. Fair warning, the underscore prefix tells me this is an undocumented API and is subject to change at any time.